# Does this use of "new Mystring" create a memory leak? C++

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, return, new-operator

Before anyone start saying that I should use `std::string`, this is an exercise part of a course, and I'm trying to learn here, not just to make something work.

The code runs ok, but I'm trying to understand when memory leaks occur, and when not. And how to check for that!!

```
Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring rhs) {
    Mystring *temp = new Mystring { *this };
    int a = strcat_s(temp->str, strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str)+1, rhs.str);
    return (*temp);
}
```

I know I'm using a `*temp` pointer there that was created with `new Mystring` and I'm aware I'm not using `delete` for that `new` (and I would not know where to put it, by the way...)

But, the code runs ok with no errors, is there a way to check for memory leaks? Is this leaking? Why? Or if not, why not?

Here is the code for everything, the problematic part is at the very end:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Mystring.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
      
    Mystring s1 {"FRANK"};
  
    s1 = s1 + "*****";
    cout << s1 << endl;               // FRANK*****       
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
#ifndef _MYSTRING_H_
#define _MYSTRING_H_

class Mystring
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Mystring& rhs);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Mystring& rhs);

private:
    char* str;      // pointer to a char[] that holds a C-style string
public:
    Mystring();                                                         // No-args constructor
    Mystring(const char* s);                                     // Overloaded constructor
    Mystring(const Mystring& source);                    // Copy constructor
    Mystring(Mystring&& source);                         // Move constructor
    ~Mystring();                                                     // Destructor

    Mystring& operator=(const Mystring& rhs);     // Copy assignment
    Mystring& operator=(Mystring&& rhs);           // Move assignment

    Mystring operator+(const Mystring rhs);

    void display() const;

    int get_length() const;                                      // getters
    const char* get_str() const;
};

#endif // _MYSTRING_H_
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Mystring.h"

 // No-args constructor
Mystring::Mystring() 
    : str{nullptr} {
    str = new char[1];
    *str = '\0';
}

// Overloaded constructor
Mystring::Mystring(const char *s) 
    : str {nullptr} {
        if (s==nullptr) {
            str = new char[1];
            *str = '\0';
        } else {
            str = new char[strlen(s)+1];
            //strcpy(str, s);
            strcpy_s(str, strlen(s)+1, s);
        }
        std::cout << "Overloaded constructor used" << std::endl;
}

// Copy constructor
Mystring::Mystring(const Mystring &source) 
    : str{nullptr} {
        str = new char[strlen(source.str)+ 1];
        //strcpy(str, source.str);
        strcpy_s(str, strlen(source.str) + 1, source.str);
        std::cout << "Copy constructor used" << std::endl;
}

// Move constructor
Mystring::Mystring( Mystring &&source) 
    :str(source.str) {
        source.str = nullptr;
        std::cout << "Move constructor used" << std::endl;
}

 // Destructor
Mystring::~Mystring() {
    delete [] str;
}

 // Copy assignment
Mystring &Mystring::operator=(const Mystring &rhs) {
    std::cout << "Using copy assignment" << std::endl;

    if (this == &rhs) 
        return *this;
    delete [] str;
    str = new char[strlen(rhs.str) + 1];
    //strcpy(str, rhs.str);
    strcpy_s(str, strlen(rhs.str) + 1, rhs.str);
    return *this;
}

// Move assignment
Mystring &Mystring::operator=( Mystring &&rhs) {
    std::cout << "Using move assignment" << std::endl;
    if (this == &rhs) 
        return *this;
    delete [] str;
    str = rhs.str;
    rhs.str = nullptr;
    return *this;
}

// Display method
void Mystring::display() const {
    std::cout << str << " : " << get_length() << std::endl;
}

// getters
int Mystring::get_length() const { return strlen(str); }
const char *Mystring::get_str() const { return str; }

// overloaded insertion operator
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Mystring &rhs) {
    os << rhs.str;
    return os;
}

// overloaded extraction operator
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Mystring &rhs) {
    char *buff = new char[1000];
    in >> buff;
    rhs = Mystring{buff};
    delete [] buff;
    return in;
}

Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring rhs) {
    Mystring temp{ *this };
    int a = strcat_s(temp.str, strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str) + 1, rhs.str);
    return (temp);
}
```

I tried to do this without `new` using:

```
Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring rhs) {
    Mystring temp { *this };
    int a = strcat_s(temp.str, strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str)+1, rhs.str);
    return (temp);
}
```

But that code throws an error when executing the destructors at the end:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED

Why is that other code NOT working?  I'm expecting the `return` function to return the `Mystring temp` by copy and then delete that temp by going out of scope, but somehow there is a move happening instead of a copy and a `str` pointer from `temp` ends up in the result object (`s1`), which causes the error when the destructor for `s1` is called.

Is there a way of doing this without `new`?

Comment: "Is there a way of doing this without "new" ?" yes. Simply dont use `new`. Why do you think you need it?

Comment: "But, the code runs ok with no errors" - a memory leak is not a compile time error, nor are many other really bad things. Just because code compiles and links (or even runs) without errors does *not*, in any way, mean that it has no flaws.

Comment: Using `new` does not create memory leaks.  Forgetting to use `delete` or using `delete` improperly, creates memory leaks.

Comment: Your copy assignment could simply be: `Mystring &Mystring::operator=(Mystring rhs) { std::swap(rhs.str, str); return *this; }`.  See the [copy and swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) as to why this simple code works (also look at the **failed solution** section at the link, as it points out the flaws in your code).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just read that copy and swap idiom, thanks for that !  a question that is maybe silly but I cannot find my error. What happens if I do "a = b" statement with swap implemented, does b get replaced by a also ? what if that was not what I want ? Definitely "swap" is a different function than "assignment", I'm not loosing standard a = b assignment functionality if it gets always replaced by swap ?

Comment: *does b get replaced by a also ?*. No. The existing object `a` is set equal to `b`, no different than if you did `int a = 10; int b = 20; a = b;`.  The `a` is now 20, and `b` hasn't changed.  The `swap` is a function that simply exchanges items.  If you also look closely, the argument `rhs` is passed *by-value*, meaning that `rhs` is a temporary copy of `b`, so again, `b` is not affected.

Comment: Also, go to the copy/swap link I posted, and understand the **How does it work?** section --- it explains in clear detail what it does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie roger that. Trying your copy assignment suggestion, but I also have a Mystring& Mystring::operator=(Mystring&& rhs) as a move assignment and now I have a "'operator =' is ambiguous". I could just delete my move assignment, but then I would be making copies sometimes when a move could have been done. What I'm missing?

Comment: @JulianA.Tinao Then you can change it to `Mystring &Mystring::operator=(const Mystring& rhs) { MyString temp = rhs; std::swap(temp.str, str); return *this; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `new` in `operator+` indeed creates a memory leak, because you are not `delete`'ing the `new`'d object before `return`'ing a copy of it.  Every `new` needs a matching `delete`, and every `new[]` needs a matching `delete[]`.

You are on the right track by removing `new` from your `operator+` code.

The problem is, when you create the `temp` object as a copy of `*this` (whether you use `new` or not), that constructor allocates its `str` member only large enough to hold a copy of the `str` value being copied from.  When you then concatenate the `rhs.str` value into `temp.str` (which is not large enough to also hold a copy of `rhs.str`), you end up writing beyond the bounds of `temp.str` into surrounding memory, corrupting that memory.

You misused the `destsz` parameter of `strcat_s()`, by giving it your *desired* `temp.str` size rather than the *actual* `temp.str` size, so it couldn't protect you from this mistake.

To do what you are attempting, you would need something more like this instead:

```
Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring &rhs) const {
    Mystring temp;
    delete[] temp.str; // to avoid leaking what your default constructor new's
    int len = strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str) + 1;
    temp.str = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(temp.str, len, str);
    strcat_s(temp.str, len, rhs.str);
    return temp;
}
```

Another option would be to give `Mystring` another constructor that lets the caller specify the initial capacity of the `str` member:

```
Mystring::Mystring(int initialCapacity) 
    : str{nullptr} {
    str = new char[initialCapacity + 1];
    *str = '\0';
}

Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring &rhs) const {
    int len = strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str);
    Mystring temp{ len };
    strcpy_s(temp.str, len+1, str);
    strcat_s(temp.str, len+1, rhs.str);
    return *temp;
}
```

Alternatively, implement a separate `operator+=` for `Mystring`, and then have `operator+` use `operator+=` to append `rhs` to `temp`:

```
Mystring& Mystring::operator+=(const Mystring &rhs) {
    int len = strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str) + 1;
    char *newStr = new char[len];
    strcpy_s(newStr, len, str);
    strcat_s(newStr, len, rhs.str);
    delete[] str;
    str = newStr;
    return *this;
}

Mystring Mystring::operator+(const Mystring &rhs) const {
    Mystring temp{ *this };
    temp += rhs;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Trying to understand memory and pointers here. What happens to the memory for the original temp.str pointer when you just overwrite it with "temp.str = new char[strlen(str) + strlen(rhs.str) + 1];", a new pointer pointing to a new place in memory.

Comment: @JulianA.Tinao That is also a memory leak.

Comment: @JulianA.Tinao You might want to add a private constructor that allows you to initialise `str` with newly allocated memory. You could then use that constructor here.

Comment: Suggestion: In the _"you end up writing into surrounding heap memory"_ part, mention _"out of bounds of ..."_ to make OP familiar with the concept.